# Win32::Serial Binary Communication

Tags: perl, serial-port, perl-module

I am trying to communicate with a UART on a embedded system using the Win32::Serial port (perl module). It seems to work fine in terms of sending the data, but for what ever reason it is unable to receive the data. I hoping is there another function besides read() that will be show the read data?

```
# Write Serial Data to Port in Little Endian Form
foreach my $intermValue (@writeData) {
    my $msb = int($intermValue/256);
    my $lsb = ($intermValue - $msb*256);

    # Writing LSB first and MSB after (Little Endian Form)
    print "Writing: LSB: ".$lsb." MSB: ".$msb."\n";
    $class->{"serialPort"}->transmit_char($lsb);
    $class->{"serialPort"}->transmit_char($msb);
}

# Read Data From Serial Port
my ($countIn, $recievedData) = $class->{"serialPort"}->read($expectedBytes);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, but it turns out there is a input function in the library, using that and a 1 second sleep I was able to make my module work.

```
# Write Serial Data to Port in Little Endian Form
foreach my $intermValue (@writeData) {
    my $msb = int($intermValue/256);
    my $lsb = ($intermValue - $msb*256);

    # Writing LSB first and MSB after (Little Endian Form)
    print "Writing: LSB: ".$lsb." MSB: ".$msb."\n";
    $class->{"serialPort"}->transmit_char($lsb);
    $class->{"serialPort"}->transmit_char($msb);
    }
    # Read Data From Serial Port
    sleep(1);
    my  $recievedData = $class->{"serialPort"}->input;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, on Win32 ActivePerl you can specify ports in the filename like this:
    open(my $fh, '+>COM1') or die "COM1: $!";
    binmode($fh);

I've successfully used this, but I never successfully used Win32:Serial!  Maybe it helps?